# Rails 4 Testing with RSpec and FactoryGirl, nested attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Ive been forcing myself to learn Rails4 with BDD and so far its come along quite nicely. However, I have been hammering at this issue for a few hours now and not come up with a reason for why it isnt working. I am currently working on testing Controllers, with only controllers and models built, no forms or anything else. It works via console, so I must simply be using something wrong.

Here is my code for reference:

/admin/pages_controller.rb

```
class Admin::PagesController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @page = Page.find_by_id(params[:id])

    @page.update_attributes!(message_params)

    redirect_to edit_admin_page_path(@page)
  end

  private
   def message_params
      params.require(:page).permit(
        :url, 
        :position, 
        :name, 
        :tags,
        images_attributes:
            [:image_file_name, :image_file_size, :image_content_type, :name, :caption, :tags, :owner_id, :owner_type],
        block_attributes:
            [:id, :body, :owner_id, :owner_type]
      )
   end

end
```

models/page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
    before_save :validate_url

    has_many :images, :as => :owner 
    has_one :block, :as => :owner

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :block

    def validate_url
        if url.blank?
          self.url = self.name.strip.downcase.gsub(" ","-").gsub(%r([^0-9a-z-]), '').gsub("--","-")
        end
    end
end
```

pages_controller_spec.rb

```
  describe "POST #update" do
    before :each do
        @page = FactoryGirl.create(:page)
    end

    it "makes sure user can upload an image" do
        image = FactoryGirl.build(:image, owner_id: @page.id, owner_type: "Page") 
        post :update, id: @page, page: { :images => [ image ]}
        @page.reload
        expect(@page.images.first).to eq(image)
    end

    it "updates values of the attributes accordingly" do
        post :update, id: @page, page: { :name => 'foo', :url => 'bar' }
        @page.reload
        expect(@page.name).to eq('foo')
    end

    it "updates the values of the block" do
        @page = FactoryGirl.create(:page_with_block)
        post :update, id: @page, page: { block: { :body => 'foobar' } }
        @page.reload
        expect(@page.block.body).to eq('foobar')        
    end

  end
```

spec/factories/blocks.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :block do
    body "<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1><section>This is the content section</section></body></html>"
  end  
end
```

spec/factories/images.rb

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    image { fixture_file_upload Rails.root.to_s + '/spec/images/1.jpg', 'image/jpg'}
    name { Faker::App.name }
    caption { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    tags { Faker::Lorem.words }
  end

end
```

RSpec results:

```
  1) Admin::PagesController POST #update makes sure user can upload an image
     Failure/Error: expect(@page.images.first).to eq(image)

       expected: #<Image id: nil, image_file_name: "1.jpg", image_file_size: 15078, image_content_type: "image/jpg", name: "Alpha", caption: "Assumenda et exercitationem quo.", tags: ["doloribus", "maiores", "dicta"], owner_id: 37, owner_type: "Page", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:111:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Admin::PagesController POST #update updates the values of the block
     Failure/Error: expect(@page.block.body).to eq('foobar')

       expected: "foobar"
            got: "<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1><section>This is the content section</section></body></html>"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:124:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.95 seconds (files took 3.71 seconds to load)
19 examples, 2 failures
```

models/image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :image_file_name, :image_file_size, :image_content_type
    before_save :clean_up

    belongs_to :page, foreign_key: "owner_id"

    has_attached_file :image
    validates_attachment_content_type(:image, :content_type => /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/)
    validates :image, :attachment_presence => true


    def clean_up
        if name.blank?
          self.name = self.image_file_name.strip.downcase.gsub(" ","-").gsub(%r([^0-9a-z-]), '').gsub("--","-")
        end
    end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated on this one, as most of the searches ive found about this subject deal with forms or params.require. I am able to update the attributes of the page itself with the second spec, but nothing I do seems to make it into the nested resources. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Edit: updated to include image model

Comment: You forgot to post `Image` class. Post it and I'll let you know what you should to do.

Comment: @ole Posted it. Sorry, I forgot to add that one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, avoid using fixture file upload with `factory_girl` http://pivotallabs.com/avoid-using-fixture-file-upload-with-factorygirl-and-paperclip/

You can simple use it like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    image { File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/images/1.jpg') }
    name { Faker::App.name }
    caption { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    tags { Faker::Lorem.words }
  end
end
```

It's not a clear answer, it's just a way in the right direction:

```
describe "POST #update" do
  let(:img) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("spec/factories/files/file.csv") } 
  let!(:page) { FactoryGirl.create(:page) }
  let(:image_attrs) do 
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:image, owner: page)
  end
  let(:image) { page.images.first }

  it "makes sure user can upload an image" do
    expect do
      post :update, id: page, page: { :images_attributes => { "0" => image_params } }
    end.to change { page.reload.images.count }.by(1)

    # Now compare the attributes
    expect(image.content_type).to eq(image_attrs[:some_type])
    # ...
  end

  it "updates values of the attributes accordingly" do
    expect do
      post :update, id: page, page: { name: 'foo', url: 'bar' }
    end.to change { page.reload.name }.to("foo")
  end

  context "updates the values of the block" do
    let(:page) { FactoryGirl.create(:page_with_block) }

    it do
      expect do
        post :update, id: page, page: { block: { :body => 'foobar' } }
      end.to change { page.reload.block.body }.to("foobar")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had been using the fixture uploads because it was creating dozens of images every time I ran the spec in the system/images folder, but I added a cleanup method now, so it doesnt matter. 

I tried your code and it did not change anything, other than making me realize how silly it was to specify the Images with a foreign key instead of polymorphic. I implemented the rest as you laid it out, but the nested attributes both do not save still.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the spec to this due to comment:

```
describe "POST #update" do
let(:img) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/images/1.jpg') }
let(:image_attrs) do 
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:image, owner: page, image: img)
end
let!(:page) { FactoryGirl.create(:page_with_block) }


it "makes sure user can upload an image" do
    expect do
      post :update, id: page, page: { :images => { "0" => image_attrs } }
    end.to change { page.reload.images.count }.by(1)
end

it "updates values of the attributes accordingly" do
    post :update, id: page, page: { :name => 'foo', :url => 'bar' }
    page.reload
    expect(page.name).to eq('foo')
end

it "updates the values of the block" do
    expect do
        post :update, id: page, page: { block: { :body => 'foobar' } }
    end.to change { page.reload.block.body }.to("foobar")   
end
```

end

Problem still occurs:

```
................F.F

Failures:

  1) Admin::PagesController POST #update makes sure user can upload an image
     Failure/Error: expect do
       expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:111:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Admin::PagesController POST #update updates the values of the block
     Failure/Error: expect do
       expected result to have changed to "foobar", but did not change
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:123:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.32 seconds (files took 1.34 seconds to load)
19 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:110 # Admin::PagesController POST #update makes sure user can upload an image
rspec ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:122 # Admin::PagesController POST #update updates the values of the block
```

EDIT: 
It turns out I didnt properly allow for image_attributes to work well with paperclip and basicly a lot of minor things were wrong. I was more used to how the setup was with Rails 3, and misinterpreted how things for Rails 4 gems work.

Updated spec:

```
  describe "POST #update" do
    let(:img) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/images/1.jpg'), 'image/jpg') }
    let(:image_attrs) do 
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:image, owner: page, image: img)
    end
    let(:block_attrs) do
        FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:block, owner: page, :body => 'foobar')
    end
    let!(:page) { FactoryGirl.create(:page_with_block) }


    it "makes sure user can upload an image" do
        expect do
          post :update, id: page, page: { :images_attributes => { "0" => image_attrs } }
        end.to change { page.reload.images.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "updates values of the attributes accordingly" do
        post :update, id: page, page: { :name => 'foo', :url => 'bar' }
        page.reload
        expect(page.name).to eq('foo')
    end

    it "updates the values of the block" do
        expect do
            post :update, id: page, page: { :block_attributes => block_attrs }
        end.to change { page.reload.block.body }.to("foobar")   
    end
  end
```

Thanks to @ole for pointing me in the right direction for testing code!